# Validate String with dash in java

Tags: java

In java, how do I validate String with dash sign `-`?

Say, I will get input from user, 
Example input: `1-29`

I want to check if the value is from `1-24`, if value input is not falls within this range, then false.

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Comment: @kon i dont want someone to write code for me, i just cant figure out the algorithm to do this. Yes i did try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, then all you need to do is parse the string using Java's `split()` method. Example: `myString.split()`. This will place it into an array where each character becomes an element in the array. Assuming valid input, you then iterate through the array and select the first and last values, convert them to integers and then determine if they fit some criteria.

There may be a more efficient way to do this but that's what immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by `split(String value)` Method

Code:

```
String str="1-24";
int[] values=str.split("-");
int userInput=5;
if(userInput>=values[0] && userInput<=values[1])
{
  return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```